# MAGENTO 2.4 EXPORT CSV FILE STUCK IN QUEU AND NEVER APPEARS TO DOWNLOAD IT

Tags: magento2, csv, importexport, magento2.4

HELP..!! I am on Magento 2.4

trying to export products but EXPORT FILE STUCK IN QUEUE....

it never appears.. what can i do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i am not sure if this information is important BUT i can import without inconveniences..... my problem is just with the export process....

Answer (score 3):

To complete this queue you need to setup cron.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

otherwise you can do following way to trigger cron manually

Go to terminal : and run following command

go to your magento root

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

Comment: hello dear Murtuza, i already had ran php bin/magento cron:run in my terminal before but  csv still no appearing.... by the way this is my cpanel cron scheduled please help me to check if it looks ok...here image  [https://ibb.co/3p90nNc]

Comment: @CesarionJS please check var/export folder for csv file

Comment: thanks for being pending of my isue.... look the image

Comment: https://imgur.com/iaX8r7L as you can see theres a lot of files csv with 0 bytes

Comment: @CesarionJS please check in export folder under var you are looking in var folder only

Comment: hello dear look... i have try exporting just 10 products, it was ok... same for 100 and even 1000 BUT my 4000 products quantity was not possible....

Comment: so i think it is a memory or limitation of quantity of products to be exprted... what do i have to do to solve it????

Answer (score 0):

Please run following command to clear queue

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

Here is a blog that you need
https://magecomp.com/blog/solved-export-file-gets-message-is-added-to-queue-wait-to-get-your-file-soon-in-magento-2-3-x/

Comment: hello dear expert, and what i would expect after that... sorry i am a newbie in magento! i did what you told me but my command line shows no answers after that...  look image [https://ibb.co/YNst5pf]

Comment: After your run this command then queue will be clear and your export file will available on grid.

Comment: Here is a screenshot : https://i.imgur.com/l7ifuvo.png

Comment: hello dear i have done with the command but no appears on grid.... afterwards i try with customers main file, entity type instead of products... and the file for customers appears on grid.... [https://imgur.com/vQG076o]

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to see the export file

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by index being set to 'update on save'. I changed this to 'update on schedule' ran a reindex using command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Following this the export file appeared in the list soon after.

Hope this helps.